# Xamarin GIF animation

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

I just started developing Xamarin
But I encountered a problem
I have a login screen and I want to play gif there
but unfortunately no images are coming

Works well for png and jpeg files

my code is below;

```
Content = new StackLayout
            {
                Padding = new Thickness(10, 40, 10, 10),
                Children = {
                    new Label { Text = "Versiyon:"+DependencyService.Get<INativeCall>().getApplicationVersion(), FontSize = Device.GetNamedSize(NamedSize.Large, typeof(Label)), TextColor = Color.White, HorizontalTextAlignment=TextAlignment.Center },
                    new Image { Source = "a.gif" },
                    username,
                    password,
                    btnLogin,
                    indicator,
                    infoServer,
                    infoUpdate
                }
            };
```

Comment: did you follow all the instructions in the docs?  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/images?tabs=windows#animated-gifs

Comment: yes ı followed docs but not working

Comment: the code you posted does not set `IsAnimationPlaying` to true.  And is the image located in the same place with the same build action as your other working images?

Comment: yes it is in the same place How did I activate the IsAnimationPlaying feature but I did not

Comment: `IsAnimationPlaying` is a bool property of Image.  As noted in the docs.  Which you said you have read.

Answer (score 8):

By default, when an animated GIF is loaded it will not be played. This is because the `IsAnimationPlaying` property, that controls whether an animated GIF is playing or stopped, has a default value of `false`. This property, of type `bool`, is backed by a BindableProperty object, which means that it can be the target of a data binding, and styled.

**Therefore**, when an animated GIF is loaded it will not be played until the `IsAnimationPlaying` property is set to `true`.

Modify code of `Image` as bellow :

```
new Image { Source = "a.jpg", IsAnimationPlaying = true}
```

For example , this is my gif file :

[image]

Xaml code :

```
<Label Text="Welcome to Xamarin.Forms!" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Start" />
<Image Source="timg.gif" IsAnimationPlaying="True"/>
```

The effect :

[image]

Comment: Sorry it did not happen

Comment: **IsAnimatonPlaying = true ** does not recognize

Comment: @EnesDeniz Hi , could you share your sample here ? I will check that .

Comment: @EnesDeniz A new created sample project with the animated image .

Comment: @EnesDeniz If `GIF` file is too large ,the app will not show it immediately , need to wait for a while . Here is my sample link for reference: https://github.com/john-heaven/AppXamarinGif

Comment: finally i did thank you very much i have one more question i can't set the gif background i created because is there any possibility i used ffimageloading

Comment: @EnesDeniz Okey , If answer be helpful and have solved that , remember to mark it or vote it up . This is will be helpful for other people to know how to solve that :-) About the another question to set gif background , you need to share the more information (Code and explains ) how to set it as the background . Therefore  , you'd better create an new one question in SO . There wil be more people to see that and share their ideas there .

Comment: Delay in showing gif. My file has 154 KB in size. There is no information regarding .gif size in official documentation. I am using the .gif as loader in my app.

Comment: Cool, so easy and apt!

Answer (score 0):

Please use the nuget package - [Xamarin.FFImageLoading](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.FFImageLoading).It processes GIFs quickly.

eg XAML -
`<ffimageloading:SvgCachedImage Grid.Row="3" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"   Source="celebrate.gif" />`